# How to center a div inside a container scrollable container div whose height grows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parent div which is showing comments and the height is set to `720px`. However, it's scrollable and more comments are added and they get pushed in and a user can scroll more through them.

I want an overlay with a grey background and button but the div still scrollable.
I tried using `position: fixed` but it doesn't seem to be accomplishing what I want.

```css
.parent {
  height: 720px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want you centered div to scroll within the container or to remain visible at a location, while the container scrolls the rest of it's content?

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL yes, the centered div to scroll "with" the container but remain centered

Comment: To clarify, do you want the div to remain centered and visible when you scroll or do you want the div to stay centered at the top of the parent div when you scroll?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where the div stays centered even when you scroll.

You can then add a button if you so desire.

```css
.parent {
  height: 720px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: blue;
}

.overlay{
  background: grey;
  margin: auto 25%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="overlay">Overlay Div</div>
</div>
```